# Java, get text between string pattern

Tags: java, string

I need to get the text between the following string occurrences:

```
"--asset"

"--"
```

So from the string,

```
"jelly beans --asset the fat cow jumps over the moon --"
```

I could get just this text,

```
"the fat cow jumps over the moon"
```

As well as showing how to do this, i would really appreciate an explanation of what is going on in the code given.

Comment: Did you try to get the string ??

Comment: The string is always different.

Comment: I am asking did you try to get the string between "--asset" and "--".Saw me your code

Comment: I'm asking how to do just that, i don't know.

Comment: solution given by sanjeev is correct. Use that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `String.indexOf()` method to find `"--asset"` in target string and if found then look for matching `"--"` in target string after the `"--asset"` index using `String.indexOf()`. By this you will get two indexes and then you need to use `String.subString()` to get desired output.

Use `String.trim()` to remove extra spaces from the output.

Comment: Although his example seems to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces too. You could perform ```trim()``` afterwards.

Comment: @CanadianDavid updated to remove spaces as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks sanjeev, simple solution. Will mark as answer when SO lets me

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Glad that helped you. Have fun coding :)

Comment: @Sanjeev- This is way better than my answer.. +1.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex :

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(--$|.*--\\w+\\s+)", ""));

--$ --> $ means end of string. So --$ matches "--" at the end.
| --> means "or" operation.

\\w --> one or more alphabets a-zA-Z_
\\s+ --> one or more spaces
.* -- > Matches any character 0 or more times greedily (as long as possible)..
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex for extracting the text.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("--asset(.*)--");
String input = "jelly beans --asset the fat cow jumps over the moon --";
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1).trim());

}
```

Comment: Instead of doing substring. you can use groups().

Comment: @Sanjeev yeah, that can be used, but the regex matches `--asset` and `--`inclusive. Hence needed to trim it off by specifying index.

Comment: You can use `--asset(.*)--` as Pattern and get desired output by `m.group(1).trim()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
String result;
int start = yourString.indexOf("--asset");

if (start != -1) {
    int end = yourString.indexOf("--", start);

    if (end != -1)
        result = yourString.substring(start, end).trim();
}
```